# MySqli Prepared Statements - execute() returns false

Tags: php, mysqli, prepared-statement, execute, bindparam

**CODE:**

```
public function addVendorForm($data,$db){
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $q = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `rtl_vendor`(date,name,email,mobile_no,telephone_no,home_address_one,home_address_two,home_city,home_state,home_pincode,home_addr_proof,business_address_one,business_address_two,business_city,business_state,business_pincode,business_addr_proof,fax_no,website,contact_person_detail,account_person_detail,business_entity,business_commodity,pan_card,gst_certificate,annual_sales,vendor_references,employee_detail,director_detail,bank_name,bank_address,beneficiary_name,bank_acno,bank_ifsc,bank_cheque,notes,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');

    $q->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssssiisssssssssssssi',$date,$data['name'],$data['email'],$data['phone'],$data['telephone'], $data['home_address_one'],$data['home_address_two'],$data['home_city'],$data['home_state'],$data['home_pincode'],$data['uploaded']['home_address_proof'],$data['business_address_one'],$data['business_address_two'],$data['business_city'],$data['business_state'],$data['business_pincode'],$data['uploaded']['business_address_proof'],$data['fax_no'],$data['website'],$data['contact_person'],$data['accounts_person'],$data['business_entity'],$data['business_commodity'],$data['uploaded']['pan_card'],$data['uploaded']['gst_certificate'],$data['annual_sales'],$data['vendor_references'],$data['employee_detail'],$data['director_detail'],$data['bank_name'],$data['bank_address'],$data['beneficiary_name'],$data['bank_acno'],$data['bank_ifsc'],$data['uploaded']['cheque_leaf'],$data['notes'],$data['status']);
    if($q->execute()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

**Screenshot of My SQL Table:**

[image]

**Output:**
When I try to

> var_dump($q->execute());

It returns

> bool(false);

but **$q->prepare() and $q->bind_param();** working (returns bool(true)) perfectly. I've tested my MySqli Object to but there is no error.

> Totally 37 columns need to be added except *id(AI)* from 38.

Kindly help me to find out the mistake.

**Solution:**

```
public function addVendorForm($data,$db){
    $date = date('Y-m-d');
    $q = $db->prepare('INSERT INTO `rtl_vendor`(date,name,email,mobile_no,telephone_no,home_address_one,home_address_two,home_city,home_state,home_pincode,home_addr_proof,business_address_one,business_address_two,business_city,business_state,business_pincode,business_addr_proof,fax_no,website,contact_person_detail,account_person_detail,business_entity,business_commodity,pan_card,gst_certificate,annual_sales,vendor_references,employee_detail,director_detail,bank_name,bank_address,beneficiary_name,bank_acno,bank_ifsc,bank_cheque,notes,status) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)');

    $q->bind_param('sssssssssssssssssssssiisssssssssssssi',$date,$data['name'],$data['email'],$data['phone'],$data['telephone'], $data['home_address_one'],$data['home_address_two'],$data['home_city'],$data['home_state'],$data['home_pincode'],$data['uploaded']['home_address_proof'],$data['business_address_one'],$data['business_address_two'],$data['business_city'],$data['business_state'],$data['business_pincode'],$data['uploaded']['business_address_proof'],$data['fax_no'],$data['website'],$data['contact_person'],$data['accounts_person'],$data['business_entity'],$data['business_commodity'],$data['uploaded']['pan_card'],$data['uploaded']['gst_certificate'],$data['annual_sales'],$data['vendor_references'],$data['employee_detail'],$data['director_detail'],$data['bank_name'],$data['bank_address'],$data['beneficiary_name'],$data['bank_acno'],$data['bank_ifsc'],$data['uploaded']['cheque_leaf'],$data['notes'],$data['status']);

    $q->execute();

    print_r($q->error); // Print the Error statement if any.
    exit;

    if($q->execute()) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

In my case the error statement is - `Column 'name' cannot be null`.

Comment: How did you test for an error? Did you check `$q->error`?

Comment: Thanks @KarstenKoop..It shows the error **string(28) "Column 'name' cannot be null" **.Now I tweaked the code littlebit and its working perfectly.